# how to progmatically relocate a TextView in a layout in onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, orientation

I have a layout which I use in my ***Activity***. I want to relocate a **TextView** to a different location programatically in the **onConfigurationChanged**.

The below layout is for portrait mode. When the **orientation** changes I want the **TextView** with id **elapsedTime** to be moved next to TextView with id  **baseTime** for ***landscape*** mode and back to the same location on portrait mode.. Is this programatically possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/primary_call_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/callerName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/labelContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/labelAndNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/elapsedTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using different layout xmls for potrait and landscape orientations ?

Comment: I don't want my activity to be completely killed and restarted.. In the landscape mode I want to hide the LinearLayout with id labelContainer and move the TextView with id elapsedTime next to the TextView with id baseTime.

Comment: In that case, you might want to set the layout parameters of the views in the onConfigurationChanged() method.

Comment: I changed it to RelativeLayout now and am trying to get the layoutParams, could you please give me a sample code if you have on how to move a TextView from one RelativeLayout to another RelativeLayout programatically?

Comment: Rather than removing the view, it's better if you put the text views in both the relative layouts and change their visibilities depending on the orientation.

Comment: I am trying this approach now, but I am facing a issue in onConfigurationChange. I see a UI flicker for a second the changes to landscape mode. I have posted this query in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012709/ui-flickers-for-a-second-while-hiding-a-view-programatically-in-onconfigurationc

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 different layouts. One for your portrait and one for your landscape. The app should switch automatically

Comment: I don't want my activity to be completely killed and restarted.. In the landscape mode I want to hide the LinearLayout with id labelContainer and move the TextView with id elapsedTime next to the TextView with id baseTime

Comment: You can try to do everything with relativelayouts and then rearranhe everything. Relativelayouts are more powerful and easier to handle as linearlayouts.

Comment: I changed it to RelativeLayout now and am trying to get the layoutParams, could you please give me a sample code if you have on how to move a TextView from one RelativeLayout to another RelativeLayout programatically?

Comment: I dont have a sample code but i would suggest you to play around with the layout_below / top / left / right xml attributes and keep the textvjews in the same parent layout